# java.lang.NullPointerException: how is null being generated?

Tags: java, android

Hitting `Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{…}:` error for the motive in the title.

The stack trace points to the error in line 25

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{me.site.site/me.site.site.Splash}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at me.site.site.Splash.onCreate(Splash.java:25)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

which in the Splash.java file should be the reference to `actionBar.hide()`

```
package me.site.site;

/**
 * Created by main_user on 2015-11-27.
 */
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class Splash extends Activity {

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();

        Thread t =new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(10000);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                    Intent i =new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }

}
```

But how could this end up being null in this instance?

Styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

**Edit** as there is no response possibility on the question, following are changes to above code, inspired from `JDev's` suggestions which constitute the functioning answer:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity { [...]

getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

the latter replacing the previous two ActionBar entries.

Comment: Post your manifest and styles.xml file

Comment: `getActionBar()` can return null

Comment: Probably you are using a theme which don't use ActionBar,

Comment: Use `getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);` before calling `setContentView `

Comment: You should extend AppCompatActivity

Comment: @JDev  question amended with styles.xml

Comment: @Jerome use `getSupportActionBar` instead of `getActionBar()` & your `Splash` activity has to extend `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: @Blackbelt  Actually, the complaint appears to be on `actionBar.hide();`

Comment: Remove lines :                                           ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
 actionBar.hide();

Comment: @SuhasBachewar  that string does not look any different to me

Comment: @JDev  I had extended with AddCompatActivity, but although `import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;`  the run interrupts  `Error:(25, 50) error: incompatible types
required: android.app.ActionBar
found:    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar`

Comment: @Jerome delete `ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();` & just use `getSupportActionBar().hide()` instead